# Not displaying Time in label in kivy

Tags: python, events, time, kivy

I am kind of new to kivy and i am trying to display time in it

Here is the python code snippet(removed the unnecessary screens/parts for arbitrary reasons):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import time
from kivy.uix.label import Label
class MyScreen(Screen):
   def update(self, *args):
        self.timeb.text = time.asctime()
        return time.asctime()
class MyApp(App):
   def build(self):
        x=MyScreen()
        root = ScreenManager()
        Clock.schedule_interval(x.update, 1)
        root.add_widget(password(name='Screen0'))
        root.add_widget(Correct(name='Screena'))
        root.add_widget(MyScreen(name='Screen1'))
        s=[x,root]
        for i in s:
            return i
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

.kv file(removed the unnecessary screens/parts for arbitrary reasons):

```
MyScreen:
<MyScreen>: #
        timeb:time_box
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        pos_hint: {'top':1}
        height: "40dp"
        size_hint_y: None
        Label:
              id:time_box 
              text:root.update()
              size_hint_x: 6
              font_size:30
              font_name:"Roboto-Light.ttf"
```

As you can see in the code i have added a few screens but the My screen is the first to come up also if i change the

```
s=[x,root]
for i in s:
      return i
```

to just

```
return root
```

then the time doesn't update itself.

Could anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to type something, most probably your kv is coded wrong. Why is there that hanging `MyScreen:` and what is it assigned to? You need a main rule somewhere, but I see none. I assigned your `MyScreen:` to `<MyApp>:` as a normal `return MyScreen()` or `return some_scrmanager` would do and it works.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock
import time
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<MyApp>:
    MyScreen:
<MyScreen>: #
    timeb:time_box
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        pos_hint: {'top':1}
        height: "40dp"
        size_hint_y: None
        Label:
            id:time_box 
            text:root.update()
            size_hint_x: 6
            font_size:30
''')
class MyScreen(Screen):
   def update(self, *args):
        self.timeb.text = time.asctime()
        return time.asctime()
class MyApp(App):
   def build(self):
        x=MyScreen()
        root = ScreenManager()
        Clock.schedule_interval(x.update, 1)
        root.add_widget(MyScreen(name='Screen1'))
        s=[x,root]
        for i in s:
            return i
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

And the same kv, but more reasonable python code would looke like this:

```
<ScreenMgr>:
    MyScreen:
<MyScreen>:
    ...

class MyScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(MyScreen, self).__init__(**kw)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1)

    def update(self, *args):
        self.timeb.text = time.asctime()
        return time.asctime()

class ScreenMgr(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
   def build(self):
        x=MyScreen()
        root = ScreenMgr()
        root.add_widget(MyScreen(name='Screen1'))
        return root
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Because there's no need to call `update()` from Screen class in the building function and even outside a class where you want to use it presuming it'll run forever(Do you plan to stop time?).